# form.valid() not working in IE with jquery validation plugin 1.11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-validate

Either it's me or IE, but the truth is form.valid() is not working for me in IE (works in Chrome/Firefox). I am using following version:

- jquery 1.8.3
- validation plugin 1.11.1

I have a simple form with one field as required, when i hit the submit button the validation fires and it prompts the user to enter the value and this code is fired "alert($(this).valid());". After user enters the value and clicks on submit button i have below jquery code running:

```
$(function () {
   $('form').submit(function () {
        alert($(this).valid());
        if ($(this).valid()) {
           alert('Hello');
        }
    });
});
```

The issue is the none of the alerts are fired. What wrong i am doing here? I checked the validation plugin document and it says it does support the jquery version i am using http://jqueryvalidation.org/

> jQuery, tested with 1.6.4, 1.7.2, 1.8.3, 1.9.0

In developer tools i don't see any error

*Edit***

This form has **input of type file (for  file upload)**. If i comment/don't display it works. So i guess something to do with IE security if you have file input you can't disable submit button or so. Just my two cents!!!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do with the above code, but if you want to do something when the form is submitted you can use the [submitHandler](http://validation.bassistance.de/validate/) hook.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm trying to disable the submit button if the form is valid. The code works in almost all browsers except IE. If  you see the sample code above none of the alerts are fired....

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead, it may be more IE friendly:

```
$('form').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // disable submit button here
    }
});
```

Comment: I will try this, but if i understand it. Isn't the validate form already hooked up to submit button? I don't want to call the validate method explicitly, i just want to check of the form is valid...

Comment: Yes, when you call `.validate()` on a form, it hooks into the submit event. If you want to do anything other than submit when the form is valid, you can do it in `submitHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working reliably because your custom `submit` handler is interfering with the `submitHandler` already built into the plugin.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

> submitHandler (default: native form submit)
>  Type: Function()
>   Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets
>   the form as the only argument. **Replaces the default submit.** The right
>   place to submit a form via Ajax after it validated.

You would never need to write your own `submit` handler when using this plugin.  For reliability, just use the plugin's `submitHandler` callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({  // initialize the plugin on your form
        // rules and/or options,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // this callback function will only fire on a valid form
            // disable submit button
            // etc.        
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/zArRK/

Remember, `.validate()` is the *initialization* method for the plugin and must be called once on DOM ready.  It is not the method you call for "testing" the form.  Testing the form is done automatically by the plugin whenever certain built-in events are triggered.  You would call `.valid()` to programatically test the form, but `.valid` is not needed, for this case, as you can see by the demo.

Comment: Your demo works fine, but it is still not helping me or may be my lack of knowledge. I am using MVC and through out my project i am using client side validation and unobstru....jquery for validation. Nowhere i explicitly say .validate(). This is already hooked up to submit. What i want is after the validate is fired i want to check if it is valid and than process my other tasks. The problem is only with IE...If my form is not valid it does show messages, but if it is valid the button does not get disabled. Long story short in IE .valid() condition code is never executed. Thanks for explanation

Comment: See EDIT section in my question

Comment: @Mr.Imish, if you're using MS's `unobtrusive validation`, don't you think that would be a critical piece of information to include in your OP?  Besides the point... `.validate()` is still called... somewhere in the code.  Since with `unobtrusive`, you can't put your options inside `.validate()`, what do the MVC documents say about this?  Where do you specify your jQuery Validation options and callback functions then?

Answer (score 0):

When our company finally upgrade from IE8 to IE10 the validate function quit working. Turned out I had to call it with the form and not just the ID name like I was doing.

**Doesn't Work**

> $("#tcForm").validate({...

**Both Version Works**

> $("form").validate({...
>
> $("form#tcForm").validate({...